# Read from a file in C while its being written externally

Tags: c, linux, io

I'd like to write a small C program that reads from a file while it is actively being written to. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any more specifics about your requirements? What are you reading exactly and how is it being modified? Are you looking for changes (anywhere), lines added to the end, or something else?

Comment: This is not really a good idea.  The IO subystem handles when data is flushed from the output buffer and actually written to a file.  Unless you can force that program to flush its output buffer (meaning, you can control that program's code), you'll get very "blocky" updates.  And if you *can* control the code, there are better ways to pass messages between programs.

Comment: It's not impossible, but we can't really help you if you don't give us an idea what you have a problem with?

Comment: This is not a good idea at all if you can avoid that.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an expert so you'll have to forgive me guys if I'm totally wrong. I'm trying to send the output from a usb keyboard to a process. I thought that maybe reading from "/dev/input/by-id/usb-<my keyboard>" would give me the input I wanted. If I use scanf I'd be reading from the standard input which I don't want to. Just read the input from the usb device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have control over the writing process you should use `mmap()` with `MAP_SHARED` in both reader and writer. This way the reader will see the changes done by the writer practically immediately.

Also, note that Linux does not make any snapshot of the data in the file when you open the file, so you should see the changes that are being made in the file even if you just use `read()` and `lseek()`.

In order to determine whether a file was modified/opened/accessed/etc in Linux you can use `inotify` API (see inotify [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify)). This allows you to make your process wait for an event you're interested in until it occurs (as opposed to polling it regularly). You can also use `epoll()` or more traditional `select()` to accomplish similar result.

Comment: Can you share / suggest any practical example?

Answer (score 2):

I think that `tail -f` is exactly what you want, isn't it? Take a look at the source code: 
http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/

Or this one (not sure if updated): http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c